# How to understand a symmetric tensor?

Tags: tensors

By definition the symmetric part of the $(0, p)$ rank tensor $\mathcal T^{0}_p$

$$S_{p}T=\frac{1}{p!}\underset{\sigma}{\sum} P_{\sigma}T$$

$P_{\sigma}$ is $\sigma$-transpose operator. My question is how to understand this formula intuitively? $T$ is a given tensor. Is this about to construct a symmetric tensor from the elements of a given tensor? How to exploit the formula for the given $(0, 2)$ rank tensor below(the bottom one gives the numerical values of the elements of the top one)? The square matrices are considered.

\begin{bmatrix}
T_{11} & T_{12} & T_{13} & T_{14}\\
T_{21} & T_{22} & T_{23} & T_{24}\\
T_{31} & T_{32} & T_{33} & T_{34}\\
T_{41} & T_{42} & T_{43} & T_{44}\\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
8 & 7 & 6 & 5\\
4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: It is a symmetrization process. If you feed it a square matrix, the diagonal elements remain the same, and $a_{ij}$, with $i \neq j$, gets replaced with $(a_{ij} + a_{ji})/2$. I am not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: How does it work when $T_{ijk}$ matrix considered? $(0, 3)$ rank tensor

Comment: Every element $T_{ijk}$ is replaced with $(T_{ijk} + T_{ikj} + T_{jik} + T_{jki} + T_{kij} + T_{kji})/6$.

Comment: How apply it to the elements with repeated coefficents? $$SpT=1/3!(T_{122}+T_{122}+T_{212}+T_{221}+T_{212}+T_{221})$$ Should the repeated elements be taken in account in permutation?

Comment: @Tursinbay, the same formula holds even if there are repeated coefficients. Of course, in this case you have some simplifications, but the same formula holds. I hope this answers your last question.